# Android - How to listen for Wifi Configured Network is being deleted/removed from Wifi Setting

Tags: android, android-wifi

How do I listen if the user is removing/deleting a network that have been configured in the Wifi Settings?

[wifi settings http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7058/screenshot2012120316580.png](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7058/screenshot2012120316580.png)

For example in the image above the user clicks on 'Forget Network', how do I listen for that event?

Is there a broadcast available for that action?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38819, there is no public API for this since ICS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

This method checks onclick() of the image that it is connected to the internet or not.You can set the boolean in reverse order to disconnect the internet if user click "forget network"
Hope this may solve your problem ::

```
private boolean haveConnectedWifi;
private boolean haveConnectedMobile;

    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            haveNetworkConnection();
            if ((haveConnectedWifi)|| (haveConnectedMobile)){
                Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Internet is go!", 3000).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "No access to Internet..please try again", 3000).show();
            }
        }
    });

private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    haveConnectedWifi = false;
    haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: I don't that's what OP really wants. If I understand correctly, he wants to observe configured WiFI networks list modifications, more or less. And I'd be surprised if it was possible.

Comment: what do you mean OP? m unfamilier with this term.

Comment: Yeah, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an event that will be triggered or broadcast when the Wifi Profiles is being remove or deleted from the Wifi Settings.

Comment: @AndroidLearner OP stands for Original Poster